# Difference between console.log(obj) and console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

After receiving a JSON Object from a SDK, The amount of fields in `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` are fewer, 
but there are some fields which are in `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` but not in `console.log(obj)`.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

```
JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)
```

you can make it print more nicely. The last number determines the amount of spaces in indentation:

```
console.log(obj)
```

Using the Console API you can print any object to the console. This will work on any browser.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code that the result in console.log is mutating.

```js
const obj = {
  value: 5
};

console.log(obj);

setTimeout(() => {
  obj.value = 10;
}, 100);
```

You can get original value if use console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))

```js
const obj = {
  value: 5
};
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

setTimeout(() => {
  obj.value = 10;
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting data from json created you can make your question more clear like this way

1) **console.log(obj)** ->  means you will get json Javascript object like in javascript serialize array

2) **console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))**  -> means you will get that json Javascript object to string and then you will use for getting data in this way `for(var i in (JSON.stringify(obj)) { }` you can easily get data inside that json

**or if you want to convert again in javascript object you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` then the data becomes a JavaScript object.**

example :

```
var obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };

1) Use the JavaScript function JSON.stringify() to convert it into a string.

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);

2) Use the JavaScript function JSON.parse() to convert text-string into a JavaScript object:

var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');

1) console.log(obj); 
output : {name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York"}

2) console.log(myJSON ); 
output : {"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}

2) console.log( JSON.parse(myJSON )); 
output : {name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York"}
```

I Hope I Make it clear your question!